# Change Finder Icon Mac High Sierra

Tags: macos

I want to change the finder icon on my mac.

In my current directory I have a new finder.png that I want to use.

Running:

`sudo cp finder.png /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/`

I would expect that I would be able to change the icon, but it gives me a permission error. `Operation not permitted`

Upon inspecting the permissions it looks like only `system` has write access to this directory.

How would I modify the finder image via the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since El Capitan macOS uses the SIP feature [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) to protect certain directories on your Mac. Even root cannot do changes in these locations. You have to (at least temporarily) deactivate SIP to make your modifications.